# Multi-Select Picklist Alternative

Tags: picklist, bestpractice, multi-select

I am looking into the best alternative solution for data capturing and reporting. I am trying to avoid multi-select picklists.

I want to capture at the Opportunity level:

- Field1__c (that contains): A, B, C, D, E options.
- For each A, B, C, D, E option, there is a set of different options the user can select from

e.g.

```
A    B
1    4
2    5
3    6
     7
     8
```

As a user, I need to be able to select both A and B, but also 3, 6, 7, 8 for example.

I did think of checkboxes, but due to being so many and they could potentially change so often, it is not the best solution.

I have started to create a custom object to store all the values from the multi-select picklist and a junction object that contains the categories: A, B, C, D, E. But the user needs to be able to select more than one option for both category, but also sub-category.

I am looking into the best way to capture this data, but also to create reports.

Answer (score 1):

option 1: checkboxes

option 2: several single-select pick lists (and a global value set, perhaps)

option 3: custom object, child relationship for options

option 4: free text

option 5: the dreaded multi-select

none is perfect, each has pros and cons, 2 is kind of rubbish